# How to postback in MVC .NET in an Action Method other than Index Action Method in a particular Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, postback

To help myself learn MVC on .NET, I am trying to implement a basic calculator.

But I have found that the Default route is configured to the Index Method of the HomeController.

If I create another `ActionResult` with a `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`, for example

```
public ActionResult Calculator()
{
    return View();
}
```

When I open that page and put in my values for the calculation, the page redirects to the `Index` method of `HomeController`.

How I can I redirect back to the same page. Should I modify the RouteConfig file?

Comment: The default route is for displaying the first page when you run the program , so it shouldn't affect other `ActionResult` `return View();` ,because `return View();` will return to its own View with the same name( unless you specify where does it return to) .Can you please let us see your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie also but I think you can do the following

Return RedirectToAction("Calculator");

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your view looks like, but the real goal here is just to make sure do one thing: `POST` to the right action.

I'd say for your purposes you can get away with something like

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Calculate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBox("A");
   @Html.TextBox("B");
   @Html.TextBox("Operation");

   <input type="submit" value="Calculate!">
}
```

Note that you'll need to modify that a bit, but you get the idea.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod%29) for more information!